# Rendering a table and chart in a single PDF using spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, itext, pdf-generation, rendering

```
    package com.example.Reporting_Tool.ToolContoller;

    import java.awt.Graphics2D;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
    import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
    import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
    import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset;
    import org.jfree.data.general.DefaultPieDataset;

    import com.itextpdf.awt.DefaultFontMapper;
    import com.itextpdf.text.BaseColor;
    import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
    import com.itextpdf.text.Element;
    import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont;
    import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
    import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfImportedPage;
    import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell;
    import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
    import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
    import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfTemplate;
    import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

    public class PieChartDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            writeChartToPDF(generateBarChart(), 500, 400, "G://RT_pdf/Sample.pdf");
            writeChartToPDF(generatePieChart(), 500, 400, "G://RT_pdf/piechart.pdf");
        }
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public static void writeChartToPDF(JFreeChart chart, int width, int height, String fileName) throws Exception{
            PdfWriter writer = null;

            Document document = new Document();
            com.itextpdf.text.Document document2=new com.itextpdf.text.Document();
              PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(new float[] { 2, 1, 2 ,1});
              table.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
              table.addCell("Name");
                  table.addCell("Age");
                  table.addCell("Location");
                  table.addCell("any");
              table.setHeaderRows(1);
              PdfPCell[] cells = table.getRow(0).getCells(); 
              for (int j=0;j<cells.length;j++){
                 cells[j].setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.GRAY);
              }
                  for (int i=1;i<5;i++){
                     table.addCell("Name:"+i);
                     table.addCell("Age:"+i);
                     table.addCell("Location:"+i);
                     table.addCell("any"+i);
                  }
              com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.getInstance(document2, new FileOutputStream("G://RT_pdf/Sample.pdf"));
              document2.open();
                  document2.add(table);
              document2.close();
            try {
                writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(
                        fileName));
                document.open();
                PdfContentByte contentByte = writer.getDirectContent();
                PdfTemplate template = contentByte.createTemplate(width, height);
                Graphics2D graphics2d = template.createGraphics(width, height,
                        new DefaultFontMapper());
                java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D rectangle2d = new java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, width,
                        height);

                chart.draw(graphics2d, rectangle2d);

                graphics2d.dispose();
                contentByte.addTemplate(template, 0, 0);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            document.close();
        }



    public static JFreeChart generatePieChart() {
        DefaultPieDataset dataSet = new DefaultPieDataset();
        dataSet.setValue("China", 19.64);
        dataSet.setValue("India", 17.3);
        dataSet.setValue("United States", 4.54);
        dataSet.setValue("Indonesia", 3.4);
        dataSet.setValue("Brazil", 2.83);
        dataSet.setValue("Pakistan", 2.48);
        dataSet.setValue("Bangladesh", 2.38);

        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart(
                "World Population by countries", dataSet, true, true, false);

        return chart;
    }

    public static JFreeChart generateBarChart() {
        DefaultCategoryDataset dataSet = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
        dataSet.setValue(791, "Population", "1750 AD");
        dataSet.setValue(978, "Population", "1800 AD");
        dataSet.setValue(1262, "Population", "1850 AD");
        dataSet.setValue(1650, "Population", "1900 AD");
        dataSet.setValue(2519, "Population", "1950 AD");
        dataSet.setValue(6070, "Population", "2000 AD");

        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart(
                "World Population growth", "Year", "Population in millions",
                dataSet, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, true, false);

        return chart;
    }
}
```

- In this example I am rendering one table and one chart in the pdf by using iText in a spring boot application.
- I'm trying to generate it by just apply in the same file but it will only render one thing and that is table, chart is not rendering in the result.
- I have visited many web sites but I can't find any code to satisfy my needs.

Comment: In `writeChartToPDF` you create two `FileOutputStream` instances, one writing to a hard-coded `"G://RT_pdf/Sample.pdf"` and one writing to `fileName`. Your first call of that method in `main` has `fileName` equal to that hard coded name. In this case the second output overwrites the former. Your second call of that method has a different `fileName` value. In this case the table is written to the hard-coded path and the chart to the different one.

Answer (score 1):

You have closed the document after open, add, close..

```
document2.open();
document2.add(table);
document2.close();
```

You need to add  the table after you writer
    writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(fileName));

Comment: The OP has  *two* documents and writers etc. Each of the documents it's associated with a writer in time.

Comment: I was able to write both the table and the bar chart by doing the above .